# What kind of items does the 2000 limit include?

Tags: ingress

Ingress now has a limit of 2000 items for inventory, and I recently ran into it. Does this include ***everything***, or are certain objects such as portal keys excluded from the tally?

I have already started passing up the chance to hack lower level portals, to avoid clutter from low level XMP or resonators. Never used media, so if that is part of the limit then all of my media is going to be jettisoned soon. I did hope to hoard portal keys for opportune times - often, I pass up creating links or fields when it would add more value to a central hub and paint a giant bullseye on it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It includes ALL items, you should discard media items since they probably all have been decoded for the codes.. only new one might not have been decoded.

Comment: I confirmed that portal keys are included :( - I was at limit, dropped a portal key and could then pick up an XMP (after which it wouldn't let me pick up the key).

Comment: I suggest you get rid of your lower level Resonators and XMP bursters and give them to your lower level teammates to help them at the same time!